# Time complexity of a 3 nested for-loop

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

```
for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j<i*i; j++) {
        if(j % i == 0) {
            for(k = 0; k<j; k++) {
                //statement;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, it's been asked to find the time complexity. I think it's O(n^4), but prof. said it's wrong. Can someone explain how this works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get some idea add code to your program that counts the operations and prints the total, then try with n=1, 10, 100 and 1000.  That’s not exactly scientific but is a hint about the correct answer. If n= 1000 takes too long, try 200, 300, 400.

Now: How many steps does the innermost loop perform at most, depending on I? And for a given I, how often is the whole loop performed? And how many values of i are there? That together gives you an upper bound, and guess what - it looks like O(n^4) to me.

I’ve just typed this on my phone, so you do it *much* more carefully and you may show be able to show your professor that you are indeed right. If the code is exactly what you wrote.

A bit more precise: The inner loop for k has j iterations. j % i == 0 is true when j is a multiple of i, that is j = i, j = 2i, j = 3i, ..., j = (i-1) i. So for a given i, the executions of the inner loop are i, multiplied by the sum over j for 1 ≤ j ≤ i-1. That sum is (i-1)(i-2) / 2, so the inner loop executes i (i-1) (i-2) / 2 times, which is quite exactly $(i-1)^3 / 2$ times.

We have 0 ≤ i ≤ n-1. Ignoring i = 0 and i = 1, 1 ≤ i-1 ≤ n-2. So the number of executions of the inner loop is about $((n-3)(n-2))^2 / 8$.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. `i`-loop: $O(n)$, `j`-loop: $O(n^2)$, `if`-condition: true about every $n$th time, `k`-loop: $O(n^2)$. Together that makes $O(n\cdot n^2/n\cdot n^2)=O(n^4)$

Comment: Thanks @gnasher729 !! I approached my professor with this explanation, he says I'm right(idk why he said wrong earlier). still thanks